# TextBoxFor not respecting linefeed, carriage return in the text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am dispalying some long text in the @Html.TextBoxFor. The text contains linefeed, carriage returns etc but @Html.TextBoxFor does not seem to respect those. Any ideas what i may be missing?

Comment: Did you try @HTml.TextAreaFor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Textbox is single line per definition.

You have to use a TextArea:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor( ...
```